# Declaring a static variable inside a recursive function. Stack overflow

Tags: c++, recursion, static, stack

This code is just about the concept, it doesn't make any sense.

```
void recur(int num)
{   
    static float tmp = num * num;
    if (num == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        recur(num - 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    recur(1000000);
}
```

I thought that static variables are just using one position in memory but the call to recur function in the main is causing stack overflow failure Which does make sense whether the variable tmp were declared in the stack, but being static it is not in the stack, right?

What is the behavior of the tmp variable??

Thanks

Comment: Local variables are not the only thing that goes on the stack. There is a per-call overhead as well (most of the time, there can be exceptions).

Comment: @Frank "There is a per-call overhead as well" plus there is one local variable - `num`

Comment: Have you tried with optimizations enabled?

Comment: try what happens if you remove the static variable (and perhaps increase the number of calls)

Answer (score 4):

> I thought that static variables are just using one position in memory

You thought correctly.

> What is the behavior of the tmp variable??

There is exactly one object for the `tmp` variable. All calls to `recur` use the same object. It is initialized on the first call to the function, and destroyed after `main` returns.

---

Every function call pushes the stack down - unless that call has been optimized away by expanding the call inline (such as in the case of tail call optimization) - and a deep recursion can easily overflow the stack.

Note that your function also has an argument, which has automatic storage and may expedite the consumption of the stack.

Comment: The argument could easily be passed in a register, but the return address could not

Answer (score 1):

A static variable is not in the stack. You can consider it as a global variable. The stack overflow appears because each call pushes argument "num" onto the stack. In addition, the return address is placed on the stack, so even an "empty" function will cause an overflow (image from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)

[image]

Comment: tbh I dont know the exact rules myself, I simply refrain from using someoneelses content if possible, for wikipedia I'd guess it is fine as long as you make clear where you took it from

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++ static variables from functions, and global variables are stored in the `.data` section of memory which is separate from the stack and the heap.

There is a nice [diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#Data) in the WiKi.

As pointed out by previous answers and comments, each time you call `recur` a place for the return address and possibly (depending on the platform, I assume you are testing on x86) for the `num` parameter are allocated on the stack.

You can use a smaller recursion (say 10 iterations) and print out the addresses to see the difference between sections, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int x;

void recur(int num)
{   
    static float tmp = num * num;

    std::cout << "tmp: " << &tmp << " num: " << &num << std::endl;
    if (num == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        recur(num - 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int z;
    int *p = new int;
    std::cout << "p: " << p << " x: " << &x << " z: " << &z << std::endl;
    recur(10);

    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

An example output would look like this:

> p: 0x1c12c20 x: 0x6011b8 z: 0x7ffc0b6dd914
>   tmp: 0x6011c8 num: 0x7ffc0b6dd8fc
>   tmp: 0x6011c8 num: 0x7ffc0b6dd8dc
>   tmp: 0x6011c8 num: 0x7ffc0b6dd8bc
>   tmp: 0x6011c8 num: 0x7ffc0b6dd89c
>   tmp: 0x6011c8 num: 0x7ffc0b6dd87c
>   tmp: 0x6011c8 num: 0x7ffc0b6dd85c
>   tmp: 0x6011c8 num: 0x7ffc0b6dd83c
>   tmp: 0x6011c8 num: 0x7ffc0b6dd81c
>   tmp: 0x6011c8 num: 0x7ffc0b6dd7fc
>   tmp: 0x6011c8 num: 0x7ffc0b6dd7dc
>   tmp: 0x6011c8 num: 0x7ffc0b6dd7bc

Answer (score 0):

Each call of `recur` function will require allocation of at least `num` argument which will eat up automatic storage space.

Comment: "Your function call will require allocation" no it will not, it may allocate but not required.

Comment: @Slava Any reference for "it may allocate but not required"?

Comment: Well, due to the as-if rule, each `num` may or may not exist. It only has to behave as-though it has existed. One possibility is the tail call optimization, in which case the recursion is transformed into a loop. I'm not sure if that's what @Slava was getting at, but it's one possible example where recursion might not actually require increasing storage. Edit : Though I'm not sure in practice how smart or constrained compilers are when you introduce a `static` variable. Actually, the function has no observable behavior and can be optimized out entirely and this might not be a tail call.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Technically `recur(1000000);` can be completely removed since it does not have any side effects. But that would be "may be optimized but not required" situation.

Comment: The obvious answer is that the parameter `num` could be passed in a register whose value would be decremented before the recursive call. It isn't trivial to do that with a return address.

Comment: I think compiler will optimize "num" vartiable since enough only one place for "num"

Answer (score 0):

I have watched in the assembly of major compilers, with maximum optimization you should not have any stack overflow:

- *GCC*: simplify the function to return 0, no recursion.
- *Clang*: as GCC
- *MSVC*: perform recusive call with an inner jump (kind of tail call), only the argument of the first non recursive call is pushed on the stack.

So I guess you will not have stack overflow if you turn optimization on for this trivial case.

But I suppose your case is more complex.

If you had a function that did not caused any stack overflow without any static variable and then causes a stack overflow if you add this static variable the reason is probably a side effect on code generation of static variable initialization.

Static variable initialization is guarded by a kind of "mutex" to ensure only that the static variable is initialized only once in multi-threaded program. These mutexes cause the call to library functions. Before a call to a function the compiler must ensure that caller saved, non used argument register and callee saved register (that it would not employ) are preserved accross calls. To do that, the compiler may push register values onto the stack.

So even if the static variable initialization happens only once within program flow, its simple existence can drastically change the generated code.